# Gerar números pseudo-aleatórios

Tags: python, números-aleatórios

Dispondo de um gerador de números pseudo-aleatórios que gera uma sequência de números x1, x2, ... no intervalo [0,1]. Como transformar esses números em números y1, y2, … no intervalo [-11, 17]?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Joab. Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável´[(https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Multiplique o numero obtido por 28 e subtraia 11. Digamos que sua rotina devolva 0.1, então ( 0.1 * 28 ) - 11 = -8.2. Os resultados irão variar de -11 a 17, conforme solicitado.